# How to update node style upon zooming?

Tags: d3.js

I would like to change the node style based on its size.
In the given example, I would like to color nodes in red the zoom factor is below 0.5, otherwise use the group color. I Tried the following code, but it returns an error message: null is not an object (d3.event.transform).
According to the error code, I think d3.event.transform is not yet initialized.

Is there a way to get the zoom factor from within the node style function?

```
var node = pane.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.value*5   })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
           return (d3.event.transform.k < 0.5) ? "red": color(d.group);
    });
```

Comment: Would you mind creating a code snippet, a jsfiddle or something similar to make it easier to help you? cf. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually managed to have it working, node.on("zoom", ...) didn't work for me, but its function inside the zoomed function made the trick. I guess nodes never get zoom events, probably because the call(zoom) function is attached to the whole graph.

```
function zoomed() {
    d3.selectAll('circle').style('fill', function(d) {
        return (d.value > d3.event.transform.k) ? 'red': color(d.group);
    })
    pane.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}
```

Nodes greater than a the zoom scale get colored in red (fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pducrot/tokbs3vg/2/#&togetherjs=9D6U8g2qnD)).
This may not be the best solution, especially for large graphs, but this work.

Answer (score 2):

The shared code excerpt is not complete, but I guess that this corresponds to the code used at initial generation of the drawing, and it is not wrapped inside a listener of the 'zoom' event.

What should be done is:

1. initizalize the drawing with the default color
2. update the fill color on zoom event.

Updated code:

Initialize the drawing:

```
var node = pane.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.value*5   })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
           return color(d.group);
    });
```

Then listen to the zoom event:

```
node.on('zoom', function() {
    node.selectAll('circle')
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        return (d3.event.transform.k < 0.5) ? 'red': color(d.group);
    })
})
```

Comment: Nodes have different sizes, I'd like to change their style when they reach a specific size, such as displaying the node label or changing the node color. Their size is based on d.value. I tried to add a function on the node style, and in the zoomed function, but it doesn't work. The zoom function doesn't know about the nodes I guess.

Comment: I tried your proposal in the fiddle, it doesn't seem to work. It doesn't seem to enter the on zoom function at all (console.log(d3.event.transform.k)). The call(zoom) function is on the <g>, should it be the the node as well?

Comment: I eventually managed to have it working. Thanks for your time, node.selectAll helped me address the issue in the zoomed function (see updated fiddle).